# pandas plot bar with TWO column values as Xaxis

Tags: python, pandas, plot, bar-chart

I have the following Data_Frame (this is how the data frame was printed):

```
        Year  Month   incomes  expenses  balance
X
2022-1  2022      1  24037.25  22922.10  1115.15
2022-2  2022      2  25348.23  19150.95  6197.28
```

I would like to bar plot the last three columns as a function of the first two, the Year and Month. So  far, all answers on the Stack Overflow didn't produce the right plot.

Any help?

Comment: What is on your x-axis?  What is on your y-axis?  Stacked or grouped?

Comment: X-Axis: Year/Month; Y-Axis: grouped bars of Incomes, Expenses and Balance

Answer (score 0):

Updated following the update of the question. Assuming the 3 columns are numeric:

```
df[['incomes', 'expenses', 'balance']].plot.bar()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Absolutely! Thanks!

Comment: Dear @rehaqds, I got an exception raised: "TypeError: no numeric data to plot"

Comment: @MeirG, it means that the 3 columns are not numbers but strings. I updated the code to transform these columns into integers.

Comment: It is now "AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!"

Comment: It works on my side but I don't have the original data and copied the 2 lines provided as text. What gives print(df.dtypes) on your side before using my code?

Comment: If you run the instruction print(df.types)  (assuming that the name of the dataframe you use is df) what is the output?   It should be something like: Year         int64
Month        int64
incomes     object
expenses    object
balance     object
dtype: object

Comment: In your previous comment, the number were with dots but in the question the numbers are with commas?

Comment: (A comment paste of the df does not keep printout structure!) anyway, a row was added  with the first column as 'X' and the rest of it blank. The numbers are definitely floats with a decimal point and two digits fraction.

Comment: Please lookup the original question, the DF is as I printed it in your original version, before your modification to turn the assumed str. to int.

Comment: If now you have incomes/expenses/balance in float type, df[['incomes', 'expenses', 'balance']].plot.bar()  should work as it does on my computer.

Comment: what about the added row?

Comment: The solution provided didn't add any row but because one the column was transformed into an index it changes the display of the dataframe.  May I know if you got the plot on your computer similar to the image  in my answer?

Comment: No I didn't! The error I am getting is "No numeric data to plot"

Comment: Dear @rehaqds,
Your answer was indeed producing the right plot, only that for some reason, my numeric column were of type 'object' rather than 'float'. Once I converted them the plot was produced alright

Answer (score 0):

The problem I encountered was that the ostensibly numeric columns were in fact of type 'objects'. Converting these to 'float' solved the problem and produced the right plot.

Here is the code:

```
df_joined['X'] = df_joined['Year'].astype(str) + '-' + df_joined['Month'].astype(str)
df_joined.set_index('X', inplace=True)
print(df_joined.dtypes)
df_joined['incomes']=df_joined['incomes'].astype(float)
df_joined['expenses']=df_joined['expenses'].astype(float)
df_joined['balance']=df_joined['balance'].astype(float)
print(df_joined.dtypes)
df_joined[['incomes', 'expenses', 'balance']].plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

produces the following print-out:

```
Year         int64
Month        int64
incomes     object
expenses    object
balance     object
dtype: object
Year          int64
Month         int64
incomes     float64
expenses    float64
balance     float64
dtype: object
```

and produces the following plot:

[image]